Getting trouble in Persistence of the data in kubernetes

I have an application, which is deployed using kubernetes. I need to persist the specific   directory.
I deployed the application without using persistence first and I exec to the pod, all the files were there
So I used Volumemounts to that particular directory which I wanted to persist.
After using persistence when I exec to the pod there was no files.
I have used the same image.

What is happening and How to overcome this?

Do you have a [mcve] showing your setup?  You'd usually want to deploy your application with a StatefulSet, and have that generate persistent storage and mount it into the Pods.  Changing the Kubernetes object definition will normally delete and recreate the Pod (extremely normal, plan for this happening routinely) and any storage will hide anything that was in the original image (true for any kind of mount everywhere, except for one specific Docker-named-volume misfeature).
